# Stemming and stopwords on IBM Watson Conversation service

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

For my app domain exists a lot of specific words with synonymous. 
I need to configure Conversation service to understand custom words and their synonymous.

Is word stemming and stopwords dictionary available in Conversation service? Do i need a custom dictionary for word' synonymous? how i can build it?

Answer (score 0):

Stop words is a built-in feature in conversation service.

Right now, the best way how to approach synonyms is to add all of them in the intent examples. E.g. `#greeting` intent with examples such as `Hi`, `Hello`, `Wassup`, `Howdy`, etc.

Alternatively you can define custom entity and define all the synonyms there (there is a support for this in the UI). E.g. entity `@facility` has a value of `pool` with synonyms like `swimming pool`, `place to swim`, etc.

So yes, right now is the best to have a custom list of synonyms built with `intents` and `entities` of the conversation service.